# Can I run all the TestNG tests that do not belong to any group (in Maven)?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testng

Or in alternative formulation:

Are tests in TestNG assigned to a default group if no group is specified, and if yes, what is the name of that default group? (Yes, I have read [this post](http://markmail.org/message/vu53gw6yrvw3ndt6)).

I want to only specify a group for a TestNG test if it is a special (integration, functional, exploratory, very slow) test.
I want to keep the unit tests clean of annotations.
But I want to be able to only run the unit-tests without explicitly setting `excludedGroups` for all the other groups (new ones might be added..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JIRA, [TESTNG-160](http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/TESTNG-160), try:

```
exclude="*"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. The comment 'How about exclude="*"' of that ticket works - so maybe you can change your answer.

Comment: The correct syntax for the xml is <exclude name=".*"/> like <groups><run><exclude name=".*"/></run></groups>